# How does one handle a null PropertyColumn in joined table in quickGrid?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, quickgrid

This is my quickgrid:

```
<QuickGrid Items="@Items" Theme="MyGrid" @ref="quickGrid" Pagination="@pagination">
     <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.Id)" Sortable="true" Class="p-2" />
     <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.LabelCode)" Sortable="true" Class="p-2" />     
     <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.Employee.Name)" Sortable="true" Class="p-2" />
 </QuickGrid>
```

This is my `dbContext`:

```
_dbContext.Asset   
    .Include(c => c.Employee)
    .ToListAsync();
```

`EmployeeId` is nullable.

If `EmployeeId` is null, the grid doesn't work.

How can I handle this to show empty cell?

Comment: not a great fix but if EmployeeId is null set value to zero

Comment: doesn't `p.Employee?.Name` work?

Comment: How set value to zero ?? in Ef Or In Component ??
---- And I Test `p.Employee?.Name` doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use this solution for now:

```
<TemplateColumn Title="Employee" Class="p-2" Sortable="true">
    @if (context.EmployeeId != null)
    {
        <span> @context.Employee.Name </span>
    }
</TemplateColumn>
```